# Как узнать, что пользователь прокрутил ниже шапки?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

есть сложная динамическая шапка. При скролле необходимо, чтобы её часть(средний этаж) ездил за пользователем. Нужно узнать в какой именно момент этот средний этаж пропадает из поля видимости пользователя(высоты экрана). есть идеи? Лучше на чистом JS.

Comment: Противоречие. Если средний этаж ездит за пользователем, то как он пропадет из поля видимости?

Comment: Погуглите scrollTop

Comment: Противоречий нет - как только этаж пропадает из поля видимости, к нему должен добавиться класс, к которому уже будут прикреплены соответствующие стили

Answer (score 0):

1. Находим ваш элемент на странице:

   `const el = document.querySelector("#My_Header");`
2. пишем функцию для нахождения расстояния вашей шапки до верха страницы (т.к. она не прилегает к верху):

   ```
   function offset(el) {
     var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
     scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     return rect.top + scrollTop
   }
   ```
3. Навешиваете обработчик событий для прокрутки страницы на window, чтоб понимать, когда необходимо закрепить этаж шап

   ```
   window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
       scrollY = window.scrollY; 
       if (scrollY > offset(el)) {
         Ваш код для фиксации шапки (position: fixed и т.д.)
       }
   })
   ```

Comment: Божественен:) закрываю вопрос